# Get redirected URL without making a request to that URL

Tags: python, redirect, web-scraping, python-requests, urllib

Say I have a URL, `http://www.myurl.com/` and when plugged into my browser, it redirects to `http://www.anewurl.newcomain.com/`. How can I get just the redirected URL without actually making a request to it?

I've tried things like

```
r = requests.get('http://www.myurl.com/', allow_redirects=False)
```

to no avail. That is, the request object gives me no useful information:

```
{'Content-Type': 'text/html', 'X-Request-ID': 'c6b1ce55-d89c-4d56-82ba-6b9fab1432e2', 'Accept-Ranges': 'none', 'Proxy-Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Location': 'http://www.myurl.com/', 'Server': 'nginx', 'Content-Length': '178', 'X-Dc': 'chi2', 'X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies': 'none', 'X-Download-Options': 'noopen', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff, nosniff', 'Date': 'Thu, 15 Dec 2016 20:12:42 GMT', 'X-XSS-Protection': '1; mode=block'}
```

To emphasize: if I remove `allow_redirects=False` and look in the headers, I can find what I'm looking for, but this, I think, includes a request at `http://www.anewurl.newcomain.com` which I want to avoid. Note the same can be said of things like `urllib.request.urlopen(http://www.myurl.com/).url`, which returns the redirected URL, but I fear also must be making a request to it.

Any help is appreciated, including the pointing out of incorrect assumptions, e.g., perhaps I am not actually making a request to the redirected URL.

Thanks.

Comment: the `Location` header says where is the next redirect request.

Comment: @eLRuLL Ah, you're right, but in my case this only works with the additional parameter `verify=False`, which I suppose should be avoided in general. Interesting. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @eLRuLL I just noticed this doesn't work when the HTTP code is 301 - any ideas? To be clear: for such URLs, the browser correctly redirects, but  the `Location` header incorrectly displays the original URL.

Comment: it should work if you set the `allow_redirects=False`. the `Location` header is not the "original URL", but the next address to go. For me, "original" means the one we came from.

Comment: @eLRuLL I agree that it should, but it doesn't in a few of my cases. Oddly enough, when I change `get` to `post`, all my 301s change to 302s and everything works just fine. At any rate, thanks again for your comments.